# Default call to a function in html

Tags: html

I want to know is there any default function which is called when a web-page is being open?
Like in objective C viewDidLoad() is called every time we run the app.

is there any such function in html?

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, HTML is a markup language. The simplest way to have a pseudo `viewDidLoad` function is to use `window.onload`, however this needs to be paired with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

HTML doesn't even have "functions". It is not a programming language.

Various events will be fired through the DOM that you can [bind JavaScript event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) to. [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/load) suggests itself as a possibility for whatever you are trying to achieve.

```
function documentLoadHandler() {
    // do something
}

document.addEventListener('load', documentLoadHandler);
```

(Do read the documentation linked above, the standards compliant code here will not work in older versions of IE and you need to work around its limitations if you want to support it).

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a markup language, not a programming language. There are no functions as such in HTML. If you are using languages like PHP, ASP or have elements of JavaScript in your page then you can either create or in some cases use functionality like this.

For example, if you're using jQuery, you can use something like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // Do something when DOM has loaded
});
```

But no, like I said, HTML is a markup language.